# Intellij IDEA editor is unable to locate external javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, mocha.js, node-modules

I am unable to figure out why Intellij idea is unable to find external libraries. I have set those correctly (i believe) in the libraries section under JavaScript in settings.

I can see those libraries are being used when I right click on the editor and check use javascript library option.

I have checked and those are configured as global libraries under project structure.

I am able to build and run my tests using terminal in intellij.

But I have grey underline on most of external libraries and that is why I am not able to run my tests using mocha run configurations.

Could someone please explain what are the exact steps to configure external JavaScript library in Intellij IDEA? I might be setting these up everywhere because of lacking knowledge in this IDE. It should not be very difficult but I am spending my time in this endlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on a Windows 10 box using Node.js v6.9.1, Mocha v2.4.5, and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.2. I was able to successfully run Mocha tests in the IDE using these Run/Debug Configuration - Mocha settings:

Node interpreter: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Node options: none

Working directory: I put the root directory of my Node.js project here.

Environment variables: NODE_PATH=.

Mocha package: my_project_root_directory\node_modules\mocha

User interface: bdd

Checked "All in directory"

Test directory: my_project_root_directory\test

Checked "Include subdirectories"

Checked "Activate tool window"